# Lambda expression with valueof an generic IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I have the following statement:

```
AnotherClass temp = myCustomList
    .Where(x => x.bTyp != null && x.bTyp is IEnumerable<T>)
    .FirstOrDefault();`
```

The statement above says that `temp` is `null`, but it shouln't be.

`T` gets as a value a generic `List` of `MyCustomClass` like `List<MyCustomClass>`.

`x.bTyp` has as a value `typeof(IEnumerable<MyCustomClass>))`.

The debugger gives me for `myCustomList` something like this:

`bTyp = {System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[...MyCustomClass]}`

How should I rewrite the statement that `temp` is not `null` and will return an result ?

Comment: Can you just check if the object itself is null and not the type?

Comment: Yes, but it has 8 elements(`List<MyCustomClass>`) in it so it's not  `null`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404993/is-it-possible-to-define-a-generic-lambda

Comment: @willaien Actually  `x.bTyp` has a dynamic data type(it's a property), but its value is at this moment something like this `typeof(IEnumerable<MyCustomClass>))`

Comment: If you remove `x.bTyp is IEnumerable<T>` condition `temp` is still `null`?

Comment: No, I will get a result

Comment: Then the problem is that `x.bTyp` isn't a `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Ok, but when `x.bTyp` is `dynamic` it will be `IEnumerable<T>` ,that's what I thought of ?!

Comment: and are you sure that the current value of x.bTyp is IEnumerable<T>? because this is actually the problem

Answer (score 0):

Temp is null because there Where() call returns 0 results and FirstOrDefault() is returning the default (which is null).

To debug, place the cursor in the lambda expression and add a breakpoint (default: F9). Run the program.

When the debugger hits the breakpoints, place your boolean expressions ( x.bTyp != null and x.bTyp is IEnumerable) in the watch windows to verify the desired result. Chances are you're missing something here.

[image: Debugger]

Comment: ok, but  the name 'x' does not exist in the current context, before, during and after that statement, because its an lambda expression ...

Comment: Are you sure the breakpoint is *inside* of the lambda expression? Are you using Visual Studio? If so, what version?I added an image for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for the tip with the debugger.When  I type `x.bTyp` I get(shortend it)  `{System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[...MyCustomClass}....IsGenericType: true...UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "IEnumerable'1" FullName = "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[[...MyCustomClass}` and `T` is `System.Collections.Generic.List<...MyCustomClass>` hope this helps